Labeling a multiline layer in QGIS
is there any methode to create a line next to my multiline feature indicating where it starts and ends and display the length (available as one of my fields) on it at the same time? Since my line is made of many segments the expression that im using make_line(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry)) creates a straight line between these points.
And actually I want a helping line over the whole feature displayed.
My main goal is to get displayed the length of a line (multiline and therefore with curves).
It should see like this:


Hopefully I have understood your question properly. If so, what I would do is first use the 'Multipart to singleparts' tool to create a new feature layer containing  multiple linestrings generated from the parent multilines.
Vector --> Geometry Tools --> Multipart to Singlepart

Select your multiline layer from the drop down. The intention is to use the resulting layer for labelling, so instead of creating a temporary layer you can use the button to the right of the 'single parts' box to save to something more permanent.
Once that has finished, change the symbology of the new linestring layer to however you want it to look, but also set an offset to move it away from the original layer (option at the bottom of this screenshot):

Finally, set the label options on the new layer to display the length of each line by using the length function:

You may want to tidy things up a bit by playing around with the offset value and rounding the length value in the label settings.

Hi @SirLostalot, thanks a lot for your help!
It was really clever to use the tool 'Multipart to singleparts'. I could solve the problem with the segmentation.

Thanks a lot for your help!
It was really clever to use the tool 'Multipart to singleparts'. I could solve the problem with the segmentation and didnt have to code anything.
It looks pretty cool for me :)
First of all I added one more symbol layer to my 'Multipart to singleparts'-output layer to highlight the start and end of the line. This as a "Hashed Line" symbol layer type with a hash placement on the first and last vertex.


To all this symbol layer types (the hashed line and the simple line) I also gave an offset for avoiding any interference with my features.
It looked like still a little bit bad for me. So I made a couple of changes to the labels like adding buffer and placing them in a visible position (basic placement settings). After styling the lines I was having other problem with the resolution of the features after exporting to PDF.

The problem was raising up because the features have really hard curves involving angles up to 90 degrees. Since the problem was mostly on the start and end of the features I set the start and end of the lines with 0,2 Map Units. This meaning that the lines would start 0,2 Map Units and end 0,2 Map Units before their true origin and end respectively.

After changing the offset in the hashed line symbol type layer and simple line, the export in PDF looks like this!


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
